# Optional path paramter in the middle of a URL with Retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit

I got the following example:

```
 @GET("product-search/category/{categoryId}")
    fun getCategories(
        @Path("categoryId") categoryId: String,
    ): Single<ApiResponse<List<CategoryResponse>>>
```

Now we are going to add support for being logged out. For this, the endpoint is the following:

```
 @GET("product-search/noauth/category/{categoryId}")
    fun getCategories(
        @Path("categoryId") categoryId: String,
    ): Single<ApiResponse<List<CategoryResponse>>>
```

I want to pass a boolean into getCategories that adds/removes `noauth` based on if the user is logged in.

Or if there's a better or more elegant way to do this for all endpoints in the project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating a class that modify the URL. Im not super happy with it but required small changes.

```
import okhttp3.Request

class AuthUrlModifier {

    private val noAuthSupportedUrls = mapOf(
        "/service-a/" to "/service-a/noauth/",
        "/service-b/" to "/service-b/noauth/",
        "/service-c/" to "/service-c/noauth/"
    )

    fun adjustUrl(request: Request): Request {
        var url = request.url.toString()

        if ("/noauth/" !in url) {
            noAuthSupportedUrls.filterKeys { it in url }.firstNotNullOfOrNull {
                url = url.replace(it.key, it.value)
            }
        }

        return request.newBuilder()
            .url(url)
            .build()
    }

}
```

I then use this in the `okhttp` interceptor, something like this:

```
class AuthorizationInterceptor(private val tokenService: TokenService) : Interceptor {


    private val urlModifier = AuthUrlModifier()

    override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response {
        var request = chain.request()

        if (tokenService.getToken() == null) {
            request = urlModifier.adjustUrl(request)
        }
    ...
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do

```kotlin
@GET
fun getCategories(
    @Url url: String,
    @Path("categoryId") categoryId: String,
): Single<ApiResponse<List<CategoryResponse>>>
```

and pass in your url based on your boolean

Not the best solution but works.

Comment: Yeah, I would prefer not to mess around with the base URL but maybe that's what I have to do.

Comment: @Url is resolved against baseUrl so, you dont have to meddle with your baseUrl, just provide relative path